# share flask-login session in both localhost and ip

Tags: flask, session, flask-login

I have a flask running on 0.0.0.0 and I have to login in my site on "http://localhost:8080" for the first time because of some restrictions. nevermind

but the problem is when I log in on localhost, I lost log on my local IP ("http://x.x.x.x:8080") and I should log in again but I don't want to

Is there any way to log in local and IP at the same time?